# How to open Product Details tab from external link in magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.3

I am trying to open the reviews tab from a link outside of the tabs.  I tried a click() on the link and a few variations of $("selector").tabs({active:2}).

How do you target a tab to make it active for product details... is it not the jQuery UI tabs?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
   $('external_link_selector').on('click',function(){
         $('review_tab').click();
   });
```

});

Comment: I actually already tried this exact thing... targeting the a tag selector in the tab